# "time and time over" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases, poetry

What does "time and time over" mean ? I encountered this verse in a Philip Larkin poem.

> they come, they wake us  time and time over.

Answer (score 3):

It is synonymous with *time and time again*, meaning that *they came (to) wake us* repeatedly:

### [over](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over)

> 5b : once more : again

Comment: Do you have some reference? I'm not so sure on the meaning of "over" in this context.

Comment: @Carlo_R. yes; please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is more obvious if the quote is taken in context.  The first four lines of [*Days*, by Philip Larkin](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/178046) are:

> What are days for?
>   Days are where we live.
>   They come, they wake us
>   Time and time over.

Plainly, the third line's "They come" refers to the series of days we live, day after day.  "They wake us /
Time and time over" refers to people waking, morning after morning; it is stated as if mornings actively awaken us.